# Preloaded images cause hard-coded image to disappear on leaving a page

Tags: jquery, image, navigation

I have a slideshow (more like a fadeshow actually) set up with jQuery. Initially, the hard-coded image is displayed, and I preload the remaining images from an array of sources with:

```
function preload(imgArray) {
    $.each(imgArray, function() {
        $.get(this);
    });
}
```

This all works fine. However, if I navigate away from the page within the first few seconds of arriving (while preloaded images are still being downloaded, but well after the initial image has fully loaded), the original hard-coded image disappears and the red X (normally shown when an image isn't found) shows up. (only noticed in FF 23 on Windows 7 SP1)

I have never noticed it before working on this particular site. It isn't a problem, since I'm leaving the page anyway, but why does this happen? Does it have anything to do with my code, or is this standard browser behavior while a resource download is interrupted?

Comment: What browser is this happening in?

Comment: Firefox 23. I ought to have thought to include that.

Comment: are you on mac or windows?

Comment: you make sure that the issue isn't a caching issue or related to the fact that you used your back button?